# how I can connect to compose for rabbitMQ(IBM) with python and amps

Tags: python, rabbitmq, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a cloudant with python, compose for rabbitMq, and program in python to link with this queue.
Ok, for amqp in rabbitmq, I get all correctly working.
but compose for rabbitmq use amqps, and I have problem to connect this mq.
I reading many post for making security in rabbit and more another post.
but I have not connect to mq in ibm.

Comment: rabbitMQ is not from IBM and IBM MQ does not support AMPS.  IBM MQ v8 and later do support AMQP, they call this MQ Light but it does not appear to be what youa re asking about.  Removing the [ibm] tag from this question.

Comment: As I found that IBM Cloud Foundry includes RabbitMQ I am adding [ibm-cloud] and [cloudfoundry].